# Access denied when reading debuggee memory

Tags: c, debugging, winapi

I've opened a process with:

```
HANDLE CreateDebuggedProcess(LPCSTR lpApplicationName)
{
    STARTUPINFO startupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation;

    ZeroMemory(&startupInfo, sizeof(startupInfo));
    startupInfo.cb = sizeof(startupInfo);
    ZeroMemory(&processInformation, sizeof(processInformation));

    if (!CreateProcessA(
        lpApplicationName,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        FALSE,
        DEBUG_PROCESS,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        &startupInfo,
        &processInformation
    ))
    {
        return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    }

    return processInformation.hProcess;
}
```

I'm waiting for the first BreakPoint Event and then I'm trying to print the memory rip is pointing at. I get rip with Get

```
void * getRip(DWORD threadId)
{
    BOOL status = FALSE;
    CONTEXT context = { 0 };

    context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;
    HANDLE threadHandle = OpenThread(THREAD_GET_CONTEXT, FALSE, threadId);
    if (NULL != threadHandle)
    {
        if(!GetThreadContext(threadHandle, &context))
        {
            status = FALSE;
            return 0;
        }

        return (void *)context.Rip;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and the returned values seems correct. I then try to call ReadProcessMemory but I get error 299: `ReadProcessMemory: invalid argument (Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.)`.

```
BOOL queryMemory(HANDLE processHandle, void * address)
{
    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION memoryInformation = { 0 };

    if (0 == VirtualQueryEx(processHandle, address, &memoryInformation, sizeof(memoryInformation)))
    {
        printf("failed :( Lasr error: %x\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    printf("AllocProtect: %x, state: %x, type: %x\n", memoryInformation.Protect
                                                    , memoryInformation.State
                                                    , memoryInformation.Type);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Which return `AllocProtect: 1, state: 10000, type: 0`. It means I don't have access but that is weird because I should have access to everything since I've created the process.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you try read not allocated memory (`state == MEM_FREE`) - you and must got error here. you not close thread handles in `CreateDebuggedProcess` and `getRip`. you not need open thread in `getRip`. you not show how you call `ReadProcessMemory`

Comment: also you not need zero init `PROCESS_INFORMATION` and `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`

Answer (score 0):

`AllocProtect: 1, state: 10000`

0x1 as a protection constance = PAGE_NOACCESS

state 0x10000 = MEM_FREE

You can't read memory that is NOACCESS or FREE.  It needs to be MEM_COMMIT and it can't be PAGE_NOACCESS.

I assume your getRip() function is returning 0 because OpenThread or GetThreadContext is failing.  Step through the code and confirm every line is working as it should, check the return value of GetLastError() after each call to a WinAPI function to find your error.

If you cannot find an error, make sure you run as administrator and are compiling for the same architecture as the target process.